# What to use to schedule many tasks on a Debian server?

Tags: debian, task

I have root access to a Ubuntu server and am using it as the central system of an Android app (a game). Users of the app can order items that take (real) time to be virtually delivered. What happens now when a player orders a virtual item is that the server schedules a cron task. The moment the virtual delivery has to occur, the cron task is executed and the system is updated accordingly.

I have been told that sheduling many jobs like this is not suited for cron (although it works perfectly when I test it on a small scale) because cron was made for doing things periodically. This is not what my app needs. I need something that does a single task only once at a specific time. Many users will use this system so a lot of tasks will be scheduled. Other apps like Farmville have a similar system that does perfectly what I need. I was wondering what they use or what the best way is for me to handle this problem.

I'm using a PostgreSQL database so using the built-in database scheduler is an option but again I was told that this might become very slow for many tasks. Polling is another infeasible option. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be scheduling a `cron` (or `at`) job for each delivery since that can become a bit of a nightmare to monitor. Instead, I'd have a *single* `cron` job that ran periodically, every `N` minutes (where `N` is the "resolution" you need for delivery).

It would then kick up and process *all* of the deliverables that are past due.

So, let's say your resolution is one minute, and a thousand different people have orders maturing in the next sixty seconds. Rather than a thousand separate `cron` jobs, all those order will be stored in a data store of some description (database, flat file, or whatever other scheme you choose) and the single `cron` job will awaken and process them all.

So you just set up your `cron` job to:

- retrieve all items from the data store due in this period;
- deliver them to their users;
- mark them complete in the data store (or delete them from same).

Your process to order items then becomes a simple action of adding the order to the data store, with no fiddling around with trying to schedule lots of individual jobs.

---

If you need a resolution *smaller* than a minute, then `cron` is not really suited to the job. It's primarily used to schedule periodic tasks with resolutions above that threshold.

One thing you could do in that case is to schedule a job that runs every minute but stays active for the whole minute, checking (say every second) whether a delivery is required and actioning that.

However, given you're not really using `cron` for its intended purpose there, I'd consider bypassing the scheduling altogether and just running your delivery script continuously.

Of course, for added backup, you could have a `cron` job run every minute to detect if your long-running script has exited for some reason, an restart it if it has (and presumably raise an alarm so you can investigate why it went down).

That way, you get the best of both worlds, low latency delivery of your items with a well-tested method for getting your script up and running again if something goes wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, a really high resolution is necessary (1/sec). Would your advice then still apply?

Comment: @user2696806, if you need a resolution of a second then `cron` is not really suitable at all (either in my suggestion, or in your original plan which my answer was based on). It works on one-minute cycles so anything smaller than that will need a different plan of attack. See my update for some suggestions.